# fscanf and the data types it scans

Tags: c

Comparing these 2 snippets of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
    FILE *f = fopen("file","w"); 
    int i; 
    fputs("12A",f); 
    fclose(f); 
    f = fopen("file","r"); 
    fscanf(f,"%d",&i); 
    fclose(f); 
    printf("%d",i); 
    return 0; 
}
```

which outputs 12

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
    FILE *f = fopen("file","w"); 
    char c; 
    fputs("12A",f); 
    fclose(f); 
    f = fopen("file","r"); 
    fscanf(f,"%c",&c); 
    fclose(f); 
    printf("%c",c); 
    return 0; 
}
```

which outputs 1

I understand why code #1 outputs 12 as fscanf() only scans for integers, but code #2 perplexes me as fscanf() scans for data of type char, so why is it that it outputs 1?

I thank you in advance for sharing your wisdom with an amateur programmer like me!

Comment: `'1'` is the first character of the string `"12A"` which you wrote to the file. What else did you expect to read back?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are using `fscanf(f,"%d",&i);` with `%d` which makes it read an integer.

And in the second case you are using `fscanf(f,"%c",&i);` with a `%c` which makes it read a single character i.e. only a single byte.

So, in the second case it only reads `'1'`.